# Swapping byte order in an undefined data type

Tags: c++, templates, endianness

I'm writing my own binary file reader in c++. I give it a input stream and then I have a template function that takes a pointer to a type and then reads `sizeof(type)` bytes from the file and stores them in memory, starting with pointer to a type.

However, I now have a need to specify endianess of certain types. In case of big endian, I have to swap the byte ordering.

The normal `read` function looks like this:

```
template <typename T>
inline void read(T &data) {
    baseStream.read((char *)&data, sizeof(T));
}
```

I want to expand it to something like this:

```
template <typename T>
inline void read(T &data, bool isBigEndian = false) {
    baseStream.read((char *)&data, sizeof(T));
    if (isBigEndian) {
        smallToBigEndian(data);
    }
}
```

For `smallToBigEndian` I wanted to use something along the lines of

```
template <typename T>
void smallToBigEndian(T &numericData) {
    char arr[sizeof(T)] = (char*)numericData;
    std::reverse(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr));
}
```

but that doesn't work. It tells me I cannot convert `char*` to `char[sizeOfType]`, e.g. `char*` to `char[2]` for an `unsigned short`.

How can I flip bytes in a type stored in memory? How do I convince the compiler that the pointer to type in memory is an array with size of type?

Comment: Maybe [`std::endian`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/endian) might come in handy.

Comment: What's unclear about the error message? Array of `char` is not a pointer to `char`. Even though you can convert **from** an array, to a pointer to its first element, the conversion in the other direction isn't, really, possible, and compiler informs you about such fact.

Comment: Fair enough. How do I use std::endian to tell the compiler to treat certain variables as bigEndian, or use it to covert a bigEndian variable into littleEndian?

Also, why isn't the conversion possible? I specified an array of certain length, and a pointer to a type the array consists of. While it isn't the safest practice, why couldn't I redefine that part of memory as an array?

Comment: TBH: If you know in advance with fields of your stream format need to be handled in big (network) endian byte order or little endian the easiest and most reliable way is to use the functions from the `htonx()` /  `ntohx()` function family.

Comment: Reference to array of char. Use it instead of pointer to char.

Comment: But specialising smallToBigEndian for a few types that make sense in this context should be more appropriate, as you don't want endianness conversions on types that do not have endianness.

Answer (score -3):

It's best to do this by using bitwise operations without relying on explicit knowledge on the host byte order. This is conveniently handled by serialization libraries. Besides byte order, there might be problems like sign format and padding bytes.

Shameless advertising: I wrote a [library](https://github.com/Erlkoenig90/uSer) that does exactly this in a platform independent and well-defined matter.